# What does this error mean: The method...is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, gwt

I'm new to this and I can't figure out what this error means.

I've tried googling but can't make any sense out of what I am finding.

I need to interact with an API to post a ticket to a remote server, and I got this code from a tutorial that I'm following.

In this block of code I'm getting this error:

> The method postToRemoteServer(String) in the type HelpDeskTestService
>   is not applicable for the arguments (String, new
>   AsyncCallback(){})

```
sendButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            HelpDeskTestService.postToRemoteServer(
                    "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/sdpapi/request/", 
                    new AsyncCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable caught)  {
                            Window.alert("Failure getting XML through proxy");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String result) {
                            processXML(result);
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
```

Here is the code from the synchronous interface:

```
public String postToRemoteServer(final String serviceUrl)
    throws HelpDeskTestException;
```

Here is the code from the Asynchronous interface:

```
void postToRemoteServer(
        final String serviceUrl,
        AsyncCallback<String> callback);
```

And finally, here is the code from the implementation class:

```
@Override
public String postToRemoteServer(String serviceUrl)
        throws HelpDeskTestException {

    try {
        //dividing url into host: http://some.server
        //path: a/path/in/it
        //and parameters: this=that&those=others

        int hostStart= serviceUrl.indexOf("//");

        int pathStart= serviceUrl.substring(hostStart + 2).indexOf("/");

        int parameterStart= serviceUrl.substring(hostStart + 2 + pathStart).indexOf("?");

        final String serverHost= serviceUrl.substring(0, hostStart + pathStart + 2);

        final String serverPath= serviceUrl.substring(hostStart + 3, 
                hostStart + pathStart + 2 + parameterStart);

        final String serverParameters= serviceUrl.substring(hostStart + pathStart + 3 + parameterStart);

        final  URL url = new URL(serverHost);

        final URLConnection connection= url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        final OutputStreamWriter out= new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

        final BufferedReader in= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));

        out.write("POST " + serverPath + "\r\n");
        out.write("Host: " + serverHost + "\r\n");
        out.write("Accept-Encoding: identity\r\n");
        out.write("Connection: close\r\n");
        out.write("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
        out.write("Content-Length: " + serverParameters.length() + "\r\n\r\n" +
            serverParameters + "\r\n");


        String result = "";
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine=in.readLine()) != null) {
            result+= inputLine;
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();

        return result;

    }  catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new HelpDeskTestException();

    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is `HelpDeskTestService.postToRemoteServer` a call to a static method??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the asynchronous interface when calling your service. You create an instance of it using GWT.create(). Assuming your asynchronous interface is called "HelpDeskTestServiceAsync", you would do something like this:

```
HelpDeskTestServiceAsync asyncService = GWT.create(HelpDeskTestService.class);

asyncService.postToRemoteServer(
                "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/sdpapi/request/", 
                new AsyncCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught)  {
                        Window.alert("Failure getting XML through proxy");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String result) {
                        processXML(result);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Yes!  That was exactly it, thank you!!!  tutorial had this line of code: private final HelpDeskTestServiceAsync helpDeskTest= GWT.create (HelpDeskTest.class); and I updated the above to: public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    helpDeskTest.postToRemoteServer(....

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the types of the argument expressions don't match the types of the method's formal parameters.

> "The method postToRemoteServer(String) in the type HelpDeskTestService is not applicable for the arguments (String, new AsyncCallback(){})"

It is saying that you are trying to `postToRemoteServer` with two arguments, but it is declared as taking one argument.

It is not entirely clear why this is happening, but it *looks* like the you are calling a static method, and if that is the case the interfaces are moot.

Alternatively, if `HelpDeskTestService` is a variable *(tsk, tsk ... Code style violation ... tsk, tsk)* then the problem may be the variable's declared type.  If you've declared it to be `Synchronous`, then the language won't permit you to all a method in the `Asynchronous` type ... unless `Synchronous` extends `Asynchronous`.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what it says, you call it with a String and an ASyncCallback type. It needs to be called with only a String. See the API documentation on that method or the 'HelpDeskTestService' class for more informations on it's use.